# C# code executes and database table gets updated succesfully but still getting error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008

My Code executes successfully and it updates the table in database too, but still, it returns my specified error that it gets failed.

Here's my code :

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox2.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox3.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox4.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox1.Text) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBox2.Text))
    {
        if (textBox3.Text == textBox4.Text)
        {

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=DESKTOP-TAACMGJ\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=libman;Integrated Security=True");

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE logdat set pass=@pass WHERE uname=@uname AND sec_que=@sec_que AND sec_ans=@sec_ans AND type=@type", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", textBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec_ans", textBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", textBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sec_que", comboBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", comboBox2.Text);


            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            try
            {
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                con.Open();
                da.Fill(dt);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password Reset Successfull!!");
                    this.Close();
                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Password Reset Failed!! Re-Enter Details.");
                    reset();
                }

            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }


        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password Confirmation Failed!!");
            textBox3.Text = "";
            textBox4.Text = "";
        }

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Fill All The Details!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? and where? id guess it mutters something about type?

Comment: I am getting Password Reset Failed! Re-Enter Details.
from my else statement from the code. but the database table gets updated

Comment: Im surprised its not complained your query is using a reserved word ..

Comment: @BugFinder: `Type` is not a reserved keyword: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reserved-keywords-transact-sql

Comment: I swear it was .. oh well.. I'll go make that well needed tea

Comment: @BugFinder: it is f.e. in MySql but not MS-SQL-Server

Comment: Thanks @TimSchmelter I blame the lack of tea still

Comment: Your code is deceiving you. It declares a datatable (object designed to store data), you never populate it (i see no SELECT anywhere) and you spect data in it. It would have worked if in your SQL Command you have had two sentences delimited by `;`. For exampled `update blablabla set blablabla ; select * from table where blablabla`. BUT you should keep code simple, get rid of the datatable and the dataadapter, and look the return of ExecuteNonQuery. AKA. Rawitas answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExecuteNonQuery` will not return any data

```
var count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
if (count > 0) MessageBox.Show("Password Reset Successfull!!");
```

> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Its early am and Ive not had my tea yet (british I dont do coffee) but even if this isnt perfect its on the right lines for me.. running a dataset off an update command sounds wonky especially then running the command in the middle... so this looks way cleaner to me - I upvoted to counteract the down you got

Comment: I dunno, maybe it will help if you add in that the DataTable and dt.Fill are not applicable (for the reasons that you specify).

Comment: Also, i wanted to ask a question about this forum, i am new here, after this, question, when i made an another question, it gave me an error stating 'we are not accepting any questions from this account'. Is that a ban ? i mean why but ?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Comment: Looks like temporal penalty due to poor quality. Check the help area in your next question and try to improve (describe the problem/missbehaviour, check if already answered, try to make it clear, are always good tips).

Comment: @FrazzerK: i guess you have deleted some very poor questions (or answers) which still count against your account. The best to prevent this is to spend some time to improve the quality of your questions. Read: [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) Always keep in mind that this site is not a forum but a network which purpose is to help future visitors, not only you. So provide questions with all necessary informations and a meaningful title